# Punteros y violación de segmentos

Tags: c, punteros

Tengo una duda con punteros en lenguaje C, tengo este algoritmo sencillo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{ 
  char *c; // para almacenar el valor retornado por gets 
  char texto[40]; 

  printf("Introducir líneas de texto.\n"); 
  printf("Para finalizar introducir la marca EOF\n\n"); 
  // Leer la primera línea de texto 
  *c = scanf("%s", texto); 
  while (c != NULL) 
  { 
    // Operaciones con la línea de texto leída 
    // ... 
    // Leer otra línea de texto 
    *c = scanf("%s", texto); 
  } 
}
```

El problema está en que se ingresa la primera fila y sale violación del segmento como se muestra en la ejecución de ejemplo:

> Introducir líneas de texto.
>   Para finalizar introducir la marca EOF
>   
>   asdasdas
>   Violación de segmento

Hay algo que no estoy teniendo en cuenta para guardar esto en el puntero `c`, el ampersand (`&`) no lo pongo porque tengo entendido que en una cadena de caracteres no es necesario ya que el indicador (nombre de la matriz) hace referencia a la dirección.

¿Me podrían dar una manito para solucionar esta prueba de concepto? He intentado buscar en internet y sigo buscando, pero si hay alguien que conozca del tema y me aclare el concepto se lo agradeceria bastantemente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `scanf` tiene la siguiente interfaz:

```
int scanf ( const char * format, ... );
```

Donde el valor de retorno, que es un entero, indica el número de elementos leídos.

Bien, en tu código haces el siguiente uso de la función:

```
char * c;
char texto[40];

*c = scanf("%s", texto);
```

El primer detalle raro es que intentas almacenar el valor de retorno en un `char`. Con esto podrías tener problemas si la función tuviese que leer más de 255 valores (improbable pero quien sabe)

El segundo detalle (y que motiva el cierre de tu aplicación), es que el puntero `c` no está  inicializado, por lo que apunta a una dirección  aleatoria de la memoria que seguramente pertenezca a otro proceso. Esto a los Sistemas Operativos modernos no les gusta demasiado porque corrompe la memoria de otras aplicaciones, así que cuando detectan este problema matan la aplicación.

La solución  es tan sencilla como:

```
int c;
char texto[40];

c = scanf("%s", texto);
```

Por otro lado, las comprobaciones que haces sobre la variable `c` deben ser igualmente actualizadas:

```
while (c != NULL)
```

Tu idea inicial con este bucle entiendo que era leer iterativamente hasta que el usuario introducía una línea en blanco... Dado que la lectura de cadenas en C no va a dar errores, lo que puedes hacer aquí  es comprobar si la cadena `texto` tiene contenido útil  o si, en cambio, es una cadena vacía:

```
while (*texto!=0)
```

Así que como ves, para tu caso particular, puedes prescindir de la variable `c`

Comment: Gracias. Estoy leyendo un libro, noté malas prácticas. Es un ejemplo propio del libro, no es mi manera, pero copie en el editor y ejecuté para ver qué salía. Cambié la función `gets` por `scanf`, porque es mala práctica, es dañina por asignar en bloques de memoria ocupada, eso causa daños. Yo programo en una PC personal con GCC, y con este compilador no puedo ejecutar `gets` ni `fgets`. Hice la prueba con DEVc++ y efectivamente me dejó hacer la prueba, cambié dicha función y saca el mismo error. En el libro el puntero está declarado `char` y no `int`. No sé si el fin es iniciarlo con `NULL`.

Comment: @dante690dark si sigues un manual procura que no sea del año 1980 o similar sino que es necesario que el mismo esté mínimamente actualizado. Los lenguajes de programación no son algo estático y evolucionan con el tiempo para integrar mejoras y nuevas características.